# Quitar filas en tabla HTML

Tags: html

Tengo 4 elemento. El bucle lo hace bien de solo poner los atributos de los que tengan el valor de nombre==alex. Pero me carga las filas y columnas y no quiero que me salgan.

Gracias

```
<script>
    var tblusuario = document.getElementById('tbl_usuario_list');
    var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('Usuarios/');
    //var databaseRef = FirebaseFirestore.database().ref('/users');
    var rowindex = 1;

    databaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

            var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();

            var row = tblusuario.insertRow(rowindex);
            var cellId = row.insertCell(0);
            var cellNombre = row.insertCell(1);
            var cellenlace = row.insertCell(2);

            if(childData.usuario=="alex"){

                cellId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childKey));
                cellNombre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.usuario));

                var strMensaje = 'Pulsa para ver la foto';
                var urlFirebase = childData.foto_url;
                var urlFinal= strMensaje.link(urlFirebase);       
                cellenlace.innerHTML=urlFinal;

                rowindex = rowindex + 1;
            }

        });
    });
    function reload_page() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

que pasa si: pone el if() justo enseguida del foreach? 
asi:

```js
<script>
    var tblusuario = document.getElementById('tbl_usuario_list');
    var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('Usuarios/');
    //var databaseRef = FirebaseFirestore.database().ref('/users');
    var rowindex = 1;

    databaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            //usar === para comparación
            if(childData.usuario === "alex"){
                var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
                var childData = childSnapshot.val();

                var row = tblusuario.insertRow(rowindex);
                var cellId = row.insertCell(0);
                var cellNombre = row.insertCell(1);
                var cellenlace = row.insertCell(2);

                cellId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childKey));
                cellNombre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.usuario));

                var strMensaje = 'Pulsa para ver la foto';
                var urlFirebase = childData.foto_url;
                var urlFinal= strMensaje.link(urlFirebase);       
                cellenlace.innerHTML=urlFinal;

                rowindex = rowindex + 1;
            }

        });
    });
    function reload_page() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: En este caso, la tabla no carga ningún valor.